# How to send a double array from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, c++-cli

In my C# code, I have the following array:

```
var prices = new[] {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 5,};
```

I need to pass it as a parameter to my managed C++ module.

```
var discountedPrices = MyManagedCpp.GetDiscountedPrices(prices) ;
```

How should the signature of `GetDiscountedPrices` look like? In the most trivial case, when discounted prices are equal to prices, how should the C++ method `GetDiscountedPrices` look like?

Edit: I managed to get it to compile. My C# code is this:

```
    [Test]
    public void test3()
    {
        var prices = new ValueType[] {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 4, 5,};
        var t = new TestArray2(prices , 5);
    }
```

My C++ code builds:

```
        TestArray2(     
        array<double^>^ prices,int maxNumDays)
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<maxNumDays;i++)
        {
// blows up at the line below
            double price = double(prices[i]);
        }
```

However I am getting a runtime error:

System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid.

**Edit:** Kevin's solution worked. I also found a useful link:[C++/CLI keywords: Under the hood](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx)

Comment: Why the `^` in `double^`? It's clear that you can't cast `double^` to `double`. Why would you do that?

Comment: This is C++/CLI, not "Managed C++".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your managed function declaration would look something like this in the header file:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    public ref class ManagedClass {
        public:
        array<double>^ GetDiscountedPrices(array<double>^ prices);
    };
}
```

Here's an example implementation of the above function that simply subtracts a hard-coded value from each price in the input array and returns the result in a separate array:

```
using namespace SomeNamespace;

array<double>^ ManagedClass::GetDiscountedPrices(array<double>^ prices) {

    array<double>^ discountedPrices = gcnew array<double>(prices->Length);
    for(int i = 0; i < prices->Length; ++i) {
        discountedPrices[i] = prices[i] - 1.1;
    }
    return discountedPrices;
}
```

Finally, calling it from C#:

```
using SomeNamespace;

ManagedClass m = new ManagedClass();
double[] d = m.GetDiscountedPrices(new double[] { 1.3, 2.4, 3.5 });
```

**Note that if your Managed C++ function is passing the array to a native function, it will need to marshall the data to prevent the garbage collector from touching it. It's hard to show a specific example without knowing what your native function looks like, but you can find some good examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b1fy41s.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in managed C++, I believe you want the signature of `GetDiscountedPrices` to be:

```
array<double>^ GetDiscountedPrices(array<double>^ prices);
```

Comment: this does not compile: cannot use the type here without a top level '^'

Comment: The signature should be using `array<float>^`, note the carat. Also it should be `double` :)